# Asp.Net Core MVC view component with Html.Checkboxfor lambda (override model)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I need a way of referencing a different model in my view component where I'm trying to bind an Html helper object (checkboxfor).

```
@model Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableResult

@{ 
    var result = Model.Result as TenantSettingsModel;
}
    <form asp-controller="Settings" asp-action="SaveSettings" method="post">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><label for=@result.PartitionKey>Your API Key: </label> </td>
        <td>@result.PartitionKey</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for=@result.RowKey>Domain Name: </label></td>
        <td>@result.RowKey</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="@result.AutoUpdateNodes">Auto Update Nodes: </label> 
    </td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AutoUpdateNodes)</td>

    </tr>
```

MVC thinks my lambda expression is referring to my "TableResult" model versus the "TenantSettingsModel" where my "AutoUpdateProperty" exists.

**Edit:** If I cast TableResult to TenantSettingsModel in the controller, then remove my model statement in the view, I get an MVC runtime error stating the following:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableResult', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'TeamsAnalyzer.Models.TenantSettingsModel'.

This is why my view had the following code:

```
var result = Model.Result as TenantSettingsModel;
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to send `TableResult` to `View`. Could you not able to cast `TableResult` to `TenantSettingsModel` inside action method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is two fold:

1. I needed to cast the TableResult.Result as TenantSettingsModel in the controller as follows:

   ```
   TableResult retrievedResult = await tableName.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
   return View(retrievedResult.Result as TenantSettingsModel);
   ```
2. I needed to remove the @model reference to TableResult in the view component view and replace it with the correct reference as follows:

   ```
   @model TeamsAnalyzer.Models.TenantSettingsModel
   ```

I could then set my lambda expression as follows:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AutoUpdateNodes)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should cast the model at controller level which should return the model directly,

. 
.
var tenantSettingViewModel = tableResult.Result as TenantSettingsModel;
return View(tenantSettingViewModel);

This way you don't have to cast the object at View level and you can also leverage HtmlHelpers of MVC with models directly.